# Method override returns null

Tags: java, overriding

I'm newbie in Java. So question might sound simple, but I'm stuck and can not figure out why this code returns null and 0.0 ?

file: Transport.java

```
public class Transport {

        private String name;
        private double price;

    public Transport(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String carName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double carPrice(){
        return price;
    }
}
```

file: Car.java

```
public class Car extends Transport{

    protected String name;
    protected double price;

    public Car(String name, double price) {
        super(name, price);
    }

    @Override
    public String carName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public double carPrice(){
        return price * 1.5;
    }
}
```

file: Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car c = new Car("CarBrand", 1000);

        System.out.println("Name: " + c.carName());
        System.out.println("Price: " + c.carPrice());
    }
}
```

Output

```
Name: null
Price: 0.0
```

Comment: If your class is called "Car", there usually is no need to put the "car" in property names. You also might want to get used to the important bean pattern early and prefix property accessors by "get" and "set". Consider names like this:

Car myCar = new Car(...), myCar.getname()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've declared *separate* `name` and `price` variables in `Car`, and never assigned a value to them - they're not the same as the `name` and `price` variables declared (and initialized) in `Transport`.  So you're seeing the default values for `String` and `double`, basically. Get rid of those extra variables in `Car`, and use `super.carPrice()` to get the original price from `Transport`:

```
public class Car extends Transport {    
    public Car(String name, double price) {
        super(name, price);
    }

    @Override
    public double carPrice(){
        return super.carPrice() * 1.5;
    }
}
```

Note that there's no need to override `carName()` at all unless you *really* want it to change behaviour.

I'd also suggest changing `carName()` and `carPrice()` to `getName()` and `getPrice()` to be more idiomatic.

Comment: OK, got it. But then what is the right way to call method `carPrice()` from `Car` class?

Comment: @Gerardas: I'm not sure what you mean. I've shown you in the answer how you call the `Transport` implementation from `Car` to invoke the original method, which just returns the `price` variable... Use the code in my answer to replace your class, and that's all you need to do.

Comment: When was writing comment there were no code above... Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Gerardas the correct way to call the inherited method is: c.carPrice() - if it is visible from your context (depends on if it is public, package private, protected), it will just be there as if you had declared it in Car.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing both the values to parent class Transport through super(). So

```
Car c = new Car("CarBrand", 1000);
```

will eventually set

> Transport class attributes name & price.

You dont need to declare both the attributes in Car class. Car will have both attributes implicitly through inheritance. Here you are creating separate attributes for Car.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two different variables for `name`, one in Car and one in Transport. `c.carName()` returns `Car.name` which has not been initialized.

If your car class is the one below, it will work

```
public class Car extends Transport {
    public Car(String name, double price) {
        super(name, price);
    }

    @Override
    public double carPrice(){
       return price * 1.5;
    }        
}
```

the same goes for the variable `price`

Comment: This correction gives error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The field Transport.price is not visible`

Answer (score 0):

The derived class `Car` is hiding the instance variables of class `Transport` .So although you are inheriting the correctly initialized data members from `Transport` class ,but the `Car` class instance variables initilized to their default values are getting returned from `Car` class methods

Answer (score 0):

When you create the 'c' object of type Car, you assign values only for 'name' and 'price' variables of class Transport (because in your constructor you call super(name, price) that will call the constructor from your Parent class).

Here: c.carName() you call the method from your Car class (because is marked as @Override) and this one returns the value of the 'name' variable from class Car. And this variable in your case, is null because you didn't assign any value for it yet. 
You assigned the value "CarBrand" for 'name' variable of type Transport. 
The same for 'price' variable.

Answer (score 0):

The use of super will return the values which you already stored in the parent class by calling the constructor super(name, price), the use of super followed by dot notation will access the parent class method. So super.carPrice() will return the value stored in the parent class.

Also, @Override annotation should only used to change an existing method from the parent class with a new functionality in the child class with out changing the name. So in case of the @Overide for carname() you need to call the super.carname() because you are returning the value from the parent class.

In short, The reason why you are getting null and 0.0 because you are accessing the child class values when you should be accessing the parent class values.

```
    public class Car extends Transport{
        
        protected String name;
        protected double price;
    
        public Car(String name, double price) {
            super(name, price);
        }
    
        @Override
        public String carName(){
            return name;
        }
    
        @Override
        public double carPrice(){
            return price * 1.5;
        }
    }

Your class should be 

       public class Car extends Transport{
        
         
        
            public Car(String name, double price) {
                super(name, price);
            }
        
            
            public String getName(){
                return super.carName();
            }
        
            @Override
            public double carPrice(){
                return super.carPrice()* 1.5;
            }
        }
```

your main class should now be

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car c = new Car("CarBrand", 1000);
    System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());
    System.out.println("Price: " + c.carPrice());

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name and price in Car overshadow the inherited properties (name and price) from Transport.

IMHO from the class design perspective, you are suppose to inherit the two variables, name and price. That's the main idea of inheritance. If you recreate the two variables, this might have reduced the purpose and benefits of extending the Transport class. The Car should only add more properties which are not inherited from Transport.